# Excel Running Slow

Tags: excel, vba

I'm copying information from different sheets to excel and creating a new file with them. So far so good, but when I want to open the file it's too slow. The file size is about 1.30 MB. I don't have any formulas to calculate. I added that to the code

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
```

Even the macro file itself opens slowly. Can the opening of the file be improved in any way

Comment: do you have any add-ins?

Comment: No, I have some references. The already created file opens quickly. However, adding Unlist, the problem remains when I open the main macro file

Comment: do the file has external link to files saved on a slow network drive?

Comment: No, the problem is that I have 4 tables. If I don't have tables, it opens quickly, but I can't do the macro without tables

Comment: Remove all macros save it under a new name and check if it is still slow when opening. If it is still slow the problem is no programming problem and off-topic here (unless formulas or links to other files are involved). If it is fast when macros are removed, then your problem is a programming problem and we need to see the exact code that runs on opening the file.

Comment: You could avoid opening the file in the first place by using PowerQuery in the UI or ADODB in vba cf. https://youtu.be/4QuddU0GQlQ